# Has or Had in this example?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

So today I had to write this sentence and it came to me with this little doubt:

> Fixed multiple bugs when a task **has/had** no date.

I'm more convinced by *had*, I'm saying that the bugs occurred when the task had no date (in past because the bugs no longer happen BUT maybe when you read it you suspect that the problem was a task without date and this is not the case).

And with *has* you get the idea that a task without date is not the real problem but instead a situation where the bugs happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use simple past tense, simple present tense, or either of them in a relative clause in a sentence talking about the past?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72375/should-i-use-simple-past-tense-simple-present-tense-or-either-of-them-in-a-rel)

Comment: *Had* would be more natural here; look up backshifting of tenses.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan ty to both of you guys, I will look further onto this topic but your answers were really helpful

Comment: The problem with your sentence is that you're missing the parts that connect the "bug" to its cause, which makes it harder to tell from context what the tense should be. *Fixed multiple bugs that {occurred/occur} when a task {had/has} no date.*

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assumption about both meanings.

"Fixed multiple bugs when a task has no date." Here believe that I can choose to add a date to a task or not. When I chose not to add a date bugs would occur. I think you're talking about some task management app.

"Fixed multiple bugs when a task had no date." Here I understand that you are working on one task. In the past, when it didn't have a date, you fixed some bugs. Now, the task does have a date.